# Store text (emails) in MongoDB vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am using an email service API (can use either JSON or PHP) to send emails, and I want to store the replies into either MySQL or Mongo.

What do you think would be better for large amounts of email message storage, MySQL or Mongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sort of depends on what you are doing, and what kind of metadata you want to store.

I have used both, but I have recently preferred to use MongoDB just because the way you store data (document-centric) is more conducive to the type of applications I work with than relational databases.

If what you want to store is a list of emails, and the replies to that email, then MongoDB might be a good way to go, since you could create a document structure like this:

```
{
    'sender':'me@me.com,
    'subject':'Hello world!',
    'to':['tom@me.com','dick@me.com','harry@me.com'],
    'body':'Hello, World, and stuff.',
    'replies':[
        {
             'from':'tom@me.com',
             'subject':'re: Hello World!',
             'body':'Please stop sending me SPAM'
             },
        { ... next reply...}
        ]
     }
```

This makes it very nice to be able to query for specific messages and responses.  Now, if you need to be able to query by individual users, the email addresses used, etc, and your primary use-case is going to be random queries from different directions, then MySQL might be better, since MongoDB doesn't really have support for joins.